# jq + what is the right approach to replace word that retruned 56 times in json

Tags: json, linux, sed, jq

we have the following `json` file ( example with `grep` )

```
grep DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain /home/main.json

 "hadoop.proxyuser.ambari.hosts": "DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain",
                    "yarn.timeline-service.http-authentication.proxyuser.ambari.hosts": "DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain",
                    "timeline.metrics.service.webapp.address": "DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain:6188",
                    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:postgresql://DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain:5432/hive",
                    "webhcat.proxyuser.ambari.hosts": "DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain",
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

`DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain` word appears more then 56 times in the `main.json` file

and we want to replace the `DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain` with `APP_SERVER_CV02.localdomain` name

the easy way is just to do it with `sed` as

```
            sed -i s'/DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain/APP_SERVER_CV02.localdomain/g' /home/main.json
```

but as I understand better to works with `jq` when dealing with `json` files

what is the right approach to replace the `DB_SERVER_CV02.localdomain` with `APP_SERVER_CV02.localdomain` with `jq` ?

Comment: In this case `sed` is simpler and just as good. `jq` would be appropriate if you wanted to make the replacements only in certain properties.

Comment: Please provide valid, well formed example JSON input and desired results (Though not with 56 repetitions... 2 or 3 is enough for demonstration and testing purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of further information, you might consider a "global search and replace" on strings (apart from keys):

```
walk(if type == "string" 
     then sub("DB_SERVER_CV02[.]localdomain"; "APP_SERVER_CV02.localdomain") 
     else . end)
```

You may wish to tweak the `sub` command (or change it to `gsub`), depending on your actual requirements.

(You could include the above `walk` program on the command line, but I'd recommend putting it into a file and using jq with the -f option.)

If you want to change all occurrences, even in keys, then you might be able to use `sed`, but you could also use jq with `walk` along the lines shown above but using `with_entries` for the keys. Since you haven't specifically mentioned this, though, it can perhaps be left as an exercise.